# global and local variables misconception

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a question regarding the output from the following code:

```
def f():

     global s
     print(s)
     s = "That's clear."
     print(s)

s = "Python is great!"
f()
print(s)
```

The output is this:

> Python is great!
>
> That's clear.
>
> That's clear.

My question is:  Why is it the very last output (i.e. the third output) is also "That's clear" .
How come the third output is not "Python is great!" .
I thought the very last statement from the code (i.e. the print(s)) statement is outside the function f(). So shouldn't print(s) here looks at the s variable that is defined globally? in this case the globally defined variable s would refers to the value "Python is great!", isn't it?  Sorry there must be some concepts I have mis-understand. I am very newbie to python. Could someone kindly explain this simple concept.

Comment: It's obvious you get your indent wrong, so it's hard to answer about expected behavior without knowing what's the correct one.

Comment: Let's take a flying guess and suggest that as you declared `s` to be global, the redefinition of `s` in function `f` changed the global `s` to "That's clear"

Comment: @John_w, I fixed your indentation, it is obvious in this case but generally try to post the code in exactly the same format as you have locally.

Answer (score 0):

To see the output you do, the structure of you code has to be:

```
def f():
    global s
    print(s) # s outside the function
    s = "That's clear." # new global s created
    print(s) # print the new s

s = "Python is great!" # s before you call the function/get to s = "That's clear."
f() # f gets called and new global s is created
print(s) # you see the new global s created in the function
```

Making *s* global means you see it outside the scope of `f`, you have already executed the function by the time you reach the last print so now the  *s* points to `That's clear.`

If you wanted to get the output you expected, you would pass s into the function and not use the global keyword so the *s* created in `f` would be  accessible only in the scope of the function itself.

```
def f(s):
    print(s)
    s = "That's clear."
    print(s)

s = "Python is great!"
f(s)
print(s)
```

This should be a  good lesson on why using *global* is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. Does the statement "global s" inside the function f here means that the s on the second line (i.e. the print(s)) inside the function f refers to the variable s outside the function i.e. s = "Python is great!" or the "global s" is saying the third line in the function (i.e. s = "That's clear") should be made as global variable?

Comment: If you removed global, you would get a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment` error as you have reassigned s in the function, if you just had `print(s)` in the function you would see `Python is great!` as s is in the global namespace, by using global you can still access the s assigned outside the function without any error but you reassign s inside the function so because you have used global you see the new value of s outside the  f when you print s

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have declared the variable `s = "Python is great!"` globally.
You may not have indented the code properly, the below code:

```
def f():
     global s
     print(s)
     s = "That's clear."
     print(s)

     s = "Python is great!"
f()
print(s)
```

Will give you the output

> Python is great!
>
> That's clear.
>
> Python is great!

The code you have written should essentially be giving an infinite recursion and should reach the max recursion depth.

Indentation is very important in python, when you indent the function call `f()` and the statement `print(s)`, python considers both of these statements to be a part of the function `f()`. When the statement `f()` is reached during the first function call, python will automatically call the function again and repeats the whole process. In reality, you will never be able to reach the third print statement.